# Debian remove email from queue

Tags: debian, email

How I can remove specific email/domain from email queue ?
I tried to grep this email from server but no luck...

Replaced emailaddress with {email}

I'm getting in mail.log regularly

```
ul 14 10:44:53 s1 sm-mta[19534]: STARTTLS=client, relay=inmx.rambler.ru., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Jul 14 10:46:15 s1 sm-mta[19534]: STARTTLS=client, relay=imx2.rambler.ru., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Jul 14 10:46:15 s1 sm-mta[19534]: u6B8RvmL015296: to=<{email}@rambler.ru>, ctladdr=<user@host> (33/33), delay=2+23:18:18, xdelay=00:02:03, mailer=esmtp, pri=38640638, relay=imx2.rambler.ru. [81.19.66.234], dsn=4.2.0, stat=Deferred: 450 4.1.8 <user@host>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found
```

Where to start investigate ?

Comment: `450 4.1.8 <user@host>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found` means the remote host doesn't accept the message because of your sender address `user@host`.  It's most likely an anti-spam filter.

Comment: Which mail subsystem? Exim4? Postfix? Something else? (Please [edit] your question to provide this information.)

Comment: why remove it? `imx2.rambler.ru` says `450` meaning it wants you to retry it later.

Answer (score 0):

Note the mail queue ID and remove corresponding queue files either manually or using [qtool.pl](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-clear-sendmail-queue/)

For manual removal use

`rm /var/spool/mqueue/*THE-ID`

But you have either stop the sendmail or ensure it does not work on the mail at the moment. I use `fuser -k` for that.